# Not working in IE11 - meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=

Tags: php, redirect

I have a php page with the following code:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url='.$thankYouPage.'">
```

$thankYouPage is a link to the required redirection.

While this is working both in Chrome and Firefox + on my android, it is not working on IE11.
I made sure i have the meta refreash option enabled in the IE security options.

Any suggestions?

I am using this a a mean to redirect the a new page after uploading a file and submitting a form,.

Dan

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you enclose the URL portion of the content attribute in in single-quote characters if you are using complex URLs, e.g. a URL containing a semi-colon.

E.g.:

```
<?php
  print('<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=\''.$thankYouPage.'\'">');
?>
```